# How to get the current URL in browser in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application,that whenever a user opens a browser,we need to check that a site is authenticated or not.For this purpose i have to check the what url is redirecting..
Any Suggestion????

Comment: This sounds a firewall type app. It has been done - Google "android firewall without root" but you'll have to hunt for source code examples. So it appears possible but certainly not easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The Android Browser does not emit a broadcast or anything like that whenever the user opens a URL in it. Besides, the user may be using a third party browser instead of the default one.

Comment: than how to use a third party brower,or any other alternative